# Can Mutants and Masterminds materials from 2e be used in 3e?

Tags: conversion, mutants-and-masterminds

There is a sale of a lot of MM2 stuff published in Portuguese. I know that MM3 in Portuguese will be coming in the following months — is it worth getting the MM2 stuff? Can it be used readily in MM3?

Here is the English version of the full list of books included in the bundle:

- *Mutants & Masterminds* 2nd edition ("revised edition")
- *Ultimate Power*
- *Mecha & Manga*
- *Mastermind's Manual*
- *Book of Magic*
- *Agents of Freedom*
- *Mutants & Masterminds GM Screen*

Comment: Luiz, is there anything more we can add to answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Good news: it is possible to convert from 2E to 3E, though of course everything is subject to GM approval.

[This page](http://mutantsandmasterminds.com/2011/01/09/mm_second_editi-2/) has a link to a [PDF](http://freeronin.com/3e_files/MM2E3EConv.pdf) that details the process of converting from 2E to 3E.

To summarize:

- For most **abilities** that have a direct parallel (like Strength or Wisdom/Awareness) the 2E modifier becomes the 3E score.

  - Dexterity is the lower of the 2E character's ranged attack modifier or dex modifier.
  - Agility is the lower of the 2E character's dex modifier or Defense bonus.
  - Fighting is the lower of the 2E character's melee attack modifier or Defense bonus.
- **Skills** changed significantly, with many 2E skills rolled into one 3E skill.  See the PDF for full details.
- **Feats** are largely similar - most map directly 1:1 to a same-named advantage.  There's a few exceptions, detailed in the PDF.
- **Powers** are the biggest change.  3E powers are built up of Effects.  Many Powers from 2nd Edition are best built using the Affliction Effect in 3E.  Essentially, if it gives the target conditions (such as Dazed, Controlled, Prone, Helpless, Blind, etc) it is an Affliction.

  Power creation in 3E is largely based on the 2E book Ultimate Power, and (IMHO) is the most fun part of 3E.  Many 2E powers have similarly-named 3E effects.  The PDF includes easy mappings, as well as explanations for powers which are no longer present as named (such as the Trip power from 2E, which is replaced by an Affliction that can apply the vulnerable or prone conditions).

In other words, everything in 2E can be converted for 3E.  Most of the fluff (settings, character concepts, backstories, etc) is directly usable.  Character builds will require a bit of work, but there's nothing in 2E that is completely unusable in 3E.  There are a few things that are much cheaper or much more expensive between editions, usually based on how they ended up being used in actual play.

Comment: I added a list of the books included in the Bundle. I think it includes the Ultimate Power sourcebook (I retranslated as Supreme Power, but it is probably ultimate in the original).
In summary, can I play 2E as 3E? Is there any reason to avoid getting this bundle? Can 3E does everything this bundle "does"?

Comment: Yeah, Supreme Power is likely the referenced book 'Ultimate Power', which goes into detail with how to build powers in 2E.  Mecha & Manga isn't released for 3E (though you could build everything in it in 3E, theoretically), and I don't believe the magic sourcebook is either (though there is a Power Profile on Magic and a supernatural sourcebook which may cover it).  Ultimately, this bundle will give you everything you need to play 2E.  You can convert most of that to support 3E, but you would still need the 3E core book.  3E can use much of this material.

Comment: Great, I will get the Bundle then and try to start playing it soon. If I get 3e down the line I will just convert it all. Does the Ultimate Power replaces the Powers on the basic book? Or is that meant to be another option available to players?

Comment: @LuizBorges: Technically speaking, Ultimate Power was an add-on book, so it's not "official" any more than the other Green Ronin books, but yeah, some of the powers replace what was in the original book. For example, Healing and Drain work differently.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Thanks for the improved formatting!

Answer (score 3):

As regards your first question, none of the 2E material is official in 3E unless your GM approves it or it showed up in 3E material. The current (as of late 2016) live developer made the following comment regarding someone asking after Battle Form in *Mecha and Manga*:

> Many of the genre-specific powers and rules will only pop up again if we do an update of the supplement or make a different supplement that covers similar genres. For now, lot of the powers from Mecha & Manga and other 2e supplements can already be built with the 3e rules. Battle Form is simple a set of powers that has the activation flaw. If you want to keep with the original power's "you can only maintain the form for one round per rank" limitation, that's a GM call as far as the flaw value, but 4pp per 5 points to build your battle form seems appropriate (similar to how the Removable flaw works; both limit the availability of your power).

Ultimately, if you want to play 2E, those books will set you up nicely. If you want to play 3E, you will need to either buy the sourcebook or make use of [the SRD](http://d20herosrd.com). As noted by Jeff, there is a conversion guide from 2E to 3E, so you can probably convert characters over, but the mechanics and costs are different in several places.

Personally, I primarily play 2E, as I feel it's the more mature product (and has a lot more official clarification that 3E never brought over), but I've come to accept 3E as a valid system and I play the occasional game in that too.

Either way, I highly recommend dropping by the [official Green Ronin forums](http://roninarmy.com) or [one of the unofficial sites](http://echoesofthemultiverse.com) to find people to talk with and play with.

Comment: From what I noticed, the bundle includes mecha and manga, magic, supreme power, gm screen, the basic book and a few more items. It is really cheap, but I won't buy it just to fill space on the shelf..

Comment: Huh. Sounds like it was simply a bundle of books. Green Ronin never released a compilation in one book, but I know there was a Bundle of Holding for 3E, and there might have been the same for 2E at some point.

Comment: I added a list of the books included in the Bundle. Can I play 2E as 3E? Is there any reason to avoid getting this bundle? Can 3E does everything this bundle "does"?